# How to remove page name in wordpress static home page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How to remove page name in static home page.I was try this code.But no luck

```
.entry-header {
    display: none;
}
```

I am using for virtue wordpress theme.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you post the site/page link?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a separate page template for the homepage or edit the default page template (page.php in your theme's folder) and delete this:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: This is indeed the right way to go - though he don't need to create a separate template. He can edit the already existing `front-page.php` template.

Comment: Yeah.. But if he wants the title to appear on other pages except home page, then he will be needing a separate template for the homepage.

Comment: No, `front-page.php` is only used for the page defined as static front page in the reading settings. Other pages use `page.php` template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this:

```
.home.entry-header {
display: none;
}
```

Note: Adding space between .home and .entry-header did the trick.
Click here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-hide-page-title-on-static-homepage-esplanade-theme

Comment: Thanks bro..but i want remove page title in static page only.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in header.php

```
<?php
if(is_page('your static page title or slug')) ?>
<style>   
     h1.entry-header{display:none !important}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro..but i want remove page title in static page only.